# how to automatic connect to device via Bluetooth and send file in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bluetooth

how can write a program to connect nearly devices automatically via Bluetooth and send a file?
just tried with FlutterBlue package but it doesn't work

Comment: FlutterBlue is for Bluetooth Low Energy connections. You probably want to use Bluetooth Classic for your file transfer. Check out [flutter_bluetooth_serial](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bluetooth_serial) or similar packages